# How objects are stored in SFDC

Tags: object

How data is stored in SFDC objects? if you ceate a object in what structure it is created in salesforce. and what is an object and how you represent a object in Salesforce?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, API objects represent database tables that contain your organization's information. For example, the central object in the Salesforce data model represents accounts—companies and organizations involved with your business, such as customers, partners, and competitors. The term “record” describes a particular occurrence of an object (such as a specific account like “IBM” or “United Airlines” that is represented by an Account object). A record is analogous to a row in a database table.

Objects already created for you by Salesforce are called standard objects. Objects you create in your organization are called custom objects.